# Node.js memory leak in simple websocket examples

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, websocket

Here is a simple 'server.js' script that appears to be leaking memory....

```
var maxMem = 0;

var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

var wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8080});
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    ws.on('close', function() {
    global.gc();
    var mu = process.memoryUsage();
    console.log("mem: " + mu.heapUsed);
        if (mu.heapUsed > maxMem) {
            maxMem = mu.heapUsed;
            console.log("*** new max: " + maxMem);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a 'client.js' script that simply opens/closes WebSockets with a short delay between....

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');

function doCycle() {
    var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
    ws.on('open', function() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            ws.close();
            doCycle();
        }, 100);
    });
}

doCycle();
```

I have read quite a bit about memory leaks in WebSockets, though many opinions say it is really a *native* memory allocation issue in node itself...

I've tried this with node 0.10.29 as well as 0.11.13 -- same results, which is that my heap (slowly) grows over time...

I just wanted to confirm that this is in fact a known problem; or maybe my use of WebSockets here is flawed...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI:  i've just retried my experiment using sockets from the 'net' module included with node....  in this case, i did *not* see any memory leakage....

Comment: Any solutions to this?
Wherever I go, I see crippling socket memory leakage (be it Ruby or Node) I am really wondering about this.